# Will my fridge be damaged if I put a bag of ice in the fridge compartment while I wait for the repairman to fix a warm fridge/cold freezer?

Tags: refrigerator

My repairman can only come tomorrow evening and I want to keep my food fresh. ( I have a warm fridge/overly cold freezer) Can I put a bag of ice in the fridge or will that damage something in the fridge? ( or just keep the food outside?)

Comment: What temp is it at and is it holding that temp?

Comment: How would I measure the temperature ( forgive my ignorance)?

Comment: Do you have a thermometer? Either a stove or meat should work

Comment: candy thermometer? ok - will try that now. Be back with you in a while

Comment: Candy probably doesn’t measure that low. No digital either?

Comment: Candy/Oven thermometers don't always have enough range to check a refrigerator (although if it tells you 70F/25C then you know you're in trouble).  Grocery stores often sell cheap fridge thermometers, kitchen store would as well.

Comment: oven and meat thermometers only measure from 120 F and up :). Candy measures from  50F and up. So that doesn't work either. I have fever thermometers but won't measure that low either.

Comment: I’m trying to figure out if the food is already bad because if it is, the ice question is not relevant anymore. I highly recommend getting an oven or fridge thermometer to leave in there; it helps know the proper cooling level and makes sure you don’t risk food poisoning yourself

Comment: ok - basically, shelves and bins are still cool, walls are room temperature.

Comment: I would say it’s too late then

Comment: I find dry ice (frozen carbon dioxide) to be a better choice than water ice. At -109.3°F or -78.5°C, a four or five pound chunk wrapped in a towel will keep things cool for at least a couple days. The stuff evaporates rather than turning to liquid. Do things still feel cool? Is the milk or orange juice anywhere near the right temperature? Are you sure you didn't accidentally knock the cool/warm adjustment knob all the way over to warm? If freezer is not a frost free unit, you may just need to defrost in order to get the fridge running right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the fridge, but I doubt it would cause additional problems for the unit.

I wouldn't trust it to keep your food safe, though.  A single bag of ice is cold, but won't cool a large space.  If the air circulation in your refrigeration compartment is broken, the food more than a foot away from the ice is unlikely to be cooled much.  If the air circulation is operating (but blowing warm air), it could overwhelm the cooling effect of the ice.

I'd try to put everything necessary into chest coolers (maybe ask a neighbor for an extra one if necessary), then ice or dry ice from the store to keep it cool overnight until the repairman arrives.  Especially if the freezer is working, so you don't have to deal with those items.

My nearby grocery sells dry ice and it has those cheap blown styrofoam coolers on top of the frozen food chillers.  I know all this from the last time I had to do a refrigerator repair.